# Sri Ramanujacharya’s advice on why example of Kaliyan(the snake) should be emulated in preference to Kshatrabandhu’s

Tags: krishna, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, ramanujacharya

There is a story in which some devotees of the  Lord  approached Sri Ramanujacharya at Srirangam, to verify if Kshatrabandhu’s words addressed to the Lord were right. Kshatrabandhu’s words were that:-

> He worshipped the Lord and therefore hoped for his Mercy. Only through the Anugraha(grace) of the Lord could one obtain Moksha.

Sri Ramanujacharya replied to the devotees that:-

> Kshatrabandhu’s words, insofar as they emphasised that Liberation came only through the Lord’s grace, were no doubt significant . But there was a flaw in what Kshatrabandhu had said and that was  - he worshipped the Lord and therefore hoped for his mercy. This sounded as if he sought Moksha from the Lord in return for his worship. A person who had truly surrendered to God(Prapanna) would not have this attitude.

Sri Ramanujacharya told the devotees that they  should instead emulate Kaliyan, the snake.

The explanation given by Sri Ramanujacharya to those devotees was that, the submission made by Kaliyan was right and approach was proper, as the snake had told the Lord (Sri Krishna) that:-

> He lacked the capacity to worship the Lord to get rid of his sorrows. And that the Lord can expect nothing from him and only His(Lord’s) grace could save him(snake).

What are the complete details of this meeting between Sri Ramanujacharya and those devotees of the Lord at Srirangam?

In which religious text are the details of this conversation between Sri Ramanujacharya and the devotees of the Lord given?

Is there an English translation of the same?

Note-The above story is an excerpt taken from the Faith column of [The Hindu newspaper](http://www.thehindu.com/opinion/?utm_source=Google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=TH_Opinion&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIqpX89uDm2wIVFRSPCh2jSgOYEAAYASAAEgJBevD_BwE)